# Checking the Lindeberg Condition

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, convergence

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\mathbb P(X_n=\pm 1)=\frac 14$, $\mathbb P(X_n=\pm n)=\frac 1{4n^2}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=0)=\frac 12 - \frac 1{2n^2}$ for all $n\ge 1$. Define the triangular array $\{X_{nj}:1\le j\le n\}_{n\ge 1}$ by setting $X_{nj}=\frac{X_j}{\sqrt n}$. Check whether the above triangular array satisfies the Lindeberg condition.

I have calculated
$$s_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_j}{\sqrt n}$$
and
$$\sigma_{nj}^2:=\mathbb E[X_{nj}^2]=\frac 1n$$
and hence
$$S_n^2:=\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{nj}^2 = 1$$
So, I need to prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2\mathbf{1}_{|X_i|>\epsilon}]\to 0\;\; \forall \epsilon>0$$
to check the Lindeberg condition.
which is clearly false as the expression is a sum.

I must have made some mistake somewhere which I can't figure out. Please help me.

Comment: Have you considered applying the Lindeberg Condition directly to this array?

Comment: @whuber yes, but couldn't make anything of it

Comment: @whuber I tried using Lindeberg directly, and this is what I got- check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general Lindeberg condition is
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{s_n^2}E[X_{nj}^2I_{[|X_{nj}| \geq \epsilon s_n]}] = 0. \tag{1}
\end{align}

In your case, as you correctly demonstrated, $s_n^2 = 1$. But $X_{nj} = \frac{X_j}{\color{red}{\sqrt{n}}}$ instead of $X_j$. Therefore, $(1)$ should become
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}E[X_{j}^2I_{[|X_{j}| \geq \epsilon\sqrt{n}]}] = 0. \tag{2}
\end{align}
For fixed $\epsilon > 0$ and sufficiently large $n$, we have
\begin{align}
 n^{-1}\sum_{j = 1}^n E[X_{j}^2I_{[|X_{j}| \geq \epsilon\sqrt{n}]}] 
= n^{-1}\sum_{j = \lceil\epsilon\sqrt{n}\rceil}^n j^2 \times \frac{1}{2j^2} 
= \frac{n - \lceil\epsilon\sqrt{n}\rceil + 1}{2n} \to \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.  Hence the Lindeberg condition **does not** hold for this triangular array.

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1)!